# Passing an array of pointers to an unmanaged DLL function

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

I am trying to create and pass an array of pointers to an unmanaged DLL function using the following C# code.

```
[DllImport("libantumbra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
public static extern uint AnCtx_Init(IntPtr ctx);

//create context
this.ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
AnCtx_Init(ptr);//returns 0 (non-error)
this.ctx = (IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(IntPtr));

[DllImport("libantumbra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AnDevice_GetList(IntPtr ctx, out IntPtr outdevs, out int outndevs);
IntPtr devs, ndevs;
AnDevice_GetList(ctx, out devs, out ndevs); //exception occurs here
```

However upon my last call I receive an `AccessViolationException`. I think it has to do with the array pointer I am passing however I have not been able to find a solution.

The end goal I am trying to achieve here is to pass a pointer to AnDevice_GetList and with the parameter `outdevs` be left with an array that has been populated by the DLL.

Let me know if you need any further info or have any ideas for me to try.

Edit:

Here is the function I am trying to call.

Header file:

```
An_DLL AnError AnDevice_GetList(AnCtx *ctx, AnDeviceInfo ***outdevs,
                            size_t *outndevs);
typedef struct AnDevice AnDevice;
typedef int AnError;
typedef struct AnCtx AnCtx;
```

And implementation:

```
AnError AnDevice_GetList(AnCtx *ctx, AnDeviceInfo ***outdevs, size_t *outndevs)
{
    An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_DEBUG, "enumerate devices...");
    libusb_device **udevs;
    ssize_t ndevs = libusb_get_device_list(ctx->uctx, &udevs);
    if (ndevs < 0) {
        An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_ERROR, "libusb_get_device_list: %s",
               libusb_strerror(ndevs));
       return AnError_LIBUSB;
    }
    AnDeviceInfo **devs = malloc((ndevs + 1) * sizeof *devs);
    if (!devs) {
        An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_ERROR, "malloc: %s", strerror(errno));
        return AnError_MALLOCFAILED;
    }
    memset(devs, 0, (ndevs + 1) * sizeof *devs);
    size_t j = 0;
    for (ssize_t i = 0; i < ndevs; ++i) {
        libusb_device *udev = udevs[i];
        AnDeviceInfo info;
        An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_DEBUG, "device: bus %03d addr %03d",
           libusb_get_bus_number(udev), libusb_get_device_address(udev));
        if (populate_info(ctx, &info, udev))
            continue;
        An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_DEBUG, "vid 0x%04x pid 0x%04x",
               info.devdes.idVendor, info.devdes.idProduct);
        if (!match_vid_pid(info.devdes.idVendor, info.devdes.idProduct)) {
            An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_DEBUG, "  does not match Antumbra VID/PID");
            continue;
        }
        devs[j] = malloc(sizeof *devs[j]);
        if (!devs[j]) {
            An_LOG(ctx, AnLog_ERROR, "malloc: %s", strerror(errno));
            continue;
        }
        libusb_ref_device(udev);
        *devs[j] = info;
        ++j;
    }
    libusb_free_device_list(udevs, 1);
    *outdevs = devs;
    *outndevs = j;
    return AnError_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: undamaged DLLS are always the best ones to use :-)

Comment: Whoops my bad, fixed.

Comment: This is totally wrong. However, nobody knows what would be right because we can't see the other side of the interface, or know how to call it. So, at the moment, with no detail, you are on your own.

Comment: For starters, ask yourself what happens with `ptArray` and `ptr2` other than them being leaked. There are no arrays passed anywhere. Probably you just have an erroneous translation of the unmanaged function, whatever it is.

Comment: BTW adam nathans book .NET and COM is the bible for this type of question

Comment: @pm100 I'll be sure to check it out, thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan those variables are leftovers from past attempts that had failed me. I have updated my post, and would appreciate it if you would take a look.

Comment: It looks like David Heffenan's answer is closest so far. There is a question of the context creation - is that being handled correctly? What's the signature for that unmanaged function? Also, `AnDevice_GetList` calls `An_LOG` several times.. does that log output any useful information that can tell you which part of that function is getting the access violation?

Comment: Yeah,  as I added the context had been created successfully.  I'm working with the dev of the library trying to find a solution.  Unfortunately logging yields no useful information as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your unmanaged function is declared like this:

```
AnError AnDevice_GetList(AnCtx *ctx, AnDeviceInfo ***outdevs, size_t *outndevs)
```

You should translate that as:

```
[DllImport("libantumbra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AnDevice_GetList(IntPtr ctx, out IntPtr outdevs, 
    out IntPtr outndevs);
```

And this is almost exactly as you have done. The only differences are that the return value is `int` and the `outndevs` parameter is of type `IntPtr`. That's because `size_t` is pointer sized on the platforms that I am aware of.

Call it like this:

```
IntPtr ctx = ...; // create a context somehow
IntPtr devs;
IntPtr ndevs;
int retval = AnDevice_GetList(ctx, out devs, out ndevs);
if (retval != AnError_SUCCESS)
    // handle error
```

So, where could your code be going wrong? One likely explanation is that the context that you pass is invalid. Another possibility is that you execute 64 bit code and the incorrect size of `outndevs` in your translation caused the error.

This is a pretty hard API to call using p/invoke. What can you do now with `devs`. You can copy the values into an `IntPtr[]` array easily enough. And presumably the library has functions that operate on these opaque device pointers. But you have to keep hold of `devs` and pass it back to the library to deallocate it. Presumably the library exports a function to do that?

---

Based on your comments and various updates, it looks like you are not getting a proper context. We can only guess, but I expect that `AnCtx_Init` is declared as

```
AnError AnCtx_Init(AnCtx **octx)
```

That is a pointer to opaque context `AnCtx*`. Translate that as:

```
[DllImport("libantumbra.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int AnCtx_Init(out IntPtr octx);
```

Call it like this:

```
IntPtr ctx;
int retval = AnCtx_Init(out ctx);
if (retval != AnError_SUCCESS)
    // handle error
```

The big thing that you have to do now is start checking for errors. Unmanaged code won't throw exceptions. You need to do error checking yourself. It is laborious, but it must be done. Take it one function at a time. Once you are sure a function call is working, move on to the next.

Comment: Yes there is a freeList function, as well as others that act on the individual pointers as you have mentioned. Thank you for your response, I'll test it our right now and let you know the result.

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect my new C# code regarding your advice, however the exception continues to occur.

Comment: There's a fault in your code most likely. The p/invoke in my answer is good. You need to do some debugging I guess. You've not shown any indication that your context is valid. Which makes me wonder if you really read that part of my answer. You won't make progress by trying code at random. You need to spend some time understanding and debugging and gathering information.

Comment: Of course, now your edit makes my answer look silly. Never mind. I'll leave you to it. Good luck.

Comment: Huh? I've added the creation of the context (returns zero).

Comment: Your problem is precisely as I said. The context is not valid. I guess that the context init function should be `public static extern int AnCtx_Init(out IntPtr ctx);` You need to stop calling `AllocHGlobal`. You don't need to do that. You need to step back a little. It's very hard for us to have to debug all this code we cannot see. A big problem is that you don't check for errors. So you don't know that all the functions you call are failing. So, add error checking and don't proceed to function 2 until function 1 has succeeded.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. I think you perhaps are a little out of your depth. A good deal of your problems likely stem from not having experience of C and C++. C# p/invoke is the wrong place to learn about pointers. You also need to get on top of the concept of the opaque pointer. So this context, for instance, is a pointer, but you never need to know what it points to. So your call to `PtrToStructure` is very wide of the mark.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've got it working now after some brushing up on C# marshalling

Comment: Perhaps you might consider accepting the answer then, if we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Some things don't make sense in your example. You create `ptr2` and allocate space for it but never copy anything into that space, and you don't pass it to your AnDevice_GetList function so that seems completely unnecessary. You create `ptArray` but never use it anywhere either.

In this code, you're creating a managed array of IntPtr structures, and allocating memory for each of them to point to, and the size of what they are pointing to is the size of a single pointer:

```
IntPtr[] ptArray = new IntPtr[] {
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size),
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size)
};
```

To really help we need a clear understanding of exactly what `AnDevice_GetList` is going to do. If `AnDevice_GetList` is populating an array of pointers, what do they point to? Do they point to structures that were allocated by `AnDevice_GetList`? If so, then what you want to do is to create an array of `IntPtr` and pin it while you make the unmanaged call. Since you're creating an array for the call to fill, do NOT pass the array as an out parameter.

```
[DllImport("libsomething.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint AnDevice_GetList(IntPtr outdevs);

IntPtr[] ptArray = new IntPtr[numberOfPointersRequired];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(ptArray);

try
{
    AnDevice_GetList(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
}
finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
```

I left off the other parameters, because I have no idea what you're doing with them or how you're expecting them to be handled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try your approach as it makes sense. I've updated my post with the header and implementation references for getList as well.

Comment: I've updated my post to include your advice, however I am still receiving the exception.

Comment: @Erik Your signature is nothing at all like that of the unmanaged function being called.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I know, I demonstrated a simpler example of just creating an array that is expected to be populated by an unmanaged library because not enough information about the semantics of the other parameters was provided. When I typed my answer, the extra information about the function signature was not in the question.

Comment: @Erik I understand. The question has morphed somewhat!